# Is there exist compact set, that has $\{\frac{1}{2n}|n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ for internal points and has not have $\{\frac{1}{2n-1}|n\in \mathbb{N}\}$?

Tags: real-analysis

a)Is there exist compact set, that has $\{\frac{1}{2n}|n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ for internal points and has not have these points $\{\frac{1}{2n-1}|n\in \mathbb{N}\}$?

I think I found that set, if anyone can check, if it is the right one $$A=[\frac{2}{4n+1},\frac{2}{4n-1}]$$
I know that set is compact, when this set is closed and bounded.
Set A is bounded, for example in interval $(0,1)$
How to know prove, that this set is closed?

b)Also, if this set is written correctly, is then new set compact with point $0$ is internal point?

Comment: Do you mean the union of these intervals for all $n$?

Comment: Yes, union intervals for $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Well, that doesn't work, since $0$ is a limit point of the set, but not in the set.

Comment: So if $n=1$, than there is interval $[\frac{2}{5},\frac{2}{3}]$, where $\frac{1}{2}$ is internal point for this interval and so on

Comment: I understand that, but $0$ is a limit point of your expression, but not in the set.

Comment: I first have to prove, that this set without $0$ is compact, and then if $0$ is in set

Comment: Well it isn't compact, since it isn't closed...

Comment: So what set than I use, to get compact set?

Comment: That's the question, isn't it? Can't do your hw for you :P

Comment: I tried for a long time but I could not get the solution

Comment: Why not just throw in $0$ to your union of closed intervals? If you can show that is closed it's clearly also bounded hence compact.

Comment: You need to include an interval around each of the required points $1/(2n)$, in order for them to be internal points; the intervals must be small enough to exclude the forbidden points $1/(2n-1)$; and for the set to be compact, you must also include any limit points of what you already have (for example, $0$ certainly must be included).  Other than that, throw in whatever bounded set of points you like as long as you don’t hit the forbidden points.

Comment: Everythink you wrote, I understand, but I do not know how to get it?